# Why is this php function causing a sever 500 error?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to implement these two functions in a separate file `functions.php` and call it in `index.php`

```
function is_field($column, $table, $requested) {

    $is_field_query = "SELECT ".$column." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column."='".$requested."'";
    $is_field_result = $mysqli->query($is_field_query);

    $is_true = $is_field_result->num_rows;

    $is_field_result->close();

    return $is_true;

}

function get_content($column, $table, $requested) {

    $get_content_query = "SELECT ".$column." FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column."='".$requested."'";
    $get_content_result = $mysqli->query($get_content_query);

    $get_content_row = $get_content_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $get_content_content = $get_content_row["content"];

    $get_content_result->close();

    return $content;

}
```

I have tried it over and over again and I have no idea why it wont work. The first one is returning 1 for valid or 0 for invalid. The second retrieves the content from a specific cell in the MySQL table. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? "Error 500" isn't enough detail.

Comment: Turn on error reporting http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

Comment: `"SELECT $column FROM $table WHERE $column = '$requested'"` You don't need to flop in and out of quotes like that if your string is double-quoted.

Comment: If you're using `MySQLi` you can use parametric query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$mysqli` inside the function, but you never pass the MySQLi resource itself. Consider writing your function like this:

```
function is_field($mysqli, $column, $table, $requested) {
```

Or, create a class that takes a MySQLi resource and reference it with `$this->mysqli` inside your function.

Also, code like this may be another issue:

```
$is_field_result = $mysqli->query($is_field_query);

$is_true = $is_field_result->num_rows;
```

You're not checking whether `$is_field_result` is `false`; therefore, the next statement causes a fatal error, because a property can't be fetched from something that's not an object.

```
if (($is_field_result = $mysqli->query($is_field_query)) === false) {
    die($mysqli->error);
}
$is_true = $is_field_result->num_rows;
```

Comment: I've commented everything out and tried to go through it sequentially and it errors now at the initial $result.

Comment: @JamesC Should have spotted it earlier; you're not passing `$mysqli` into  your function.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason it was not working was I needed to add an extra field into the function to accept the passing of $mysqli from the connection.

```
function is_field($mysqli, $column, $table, $requested) {

$is_field_query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column='$requested'";
if (($is_field_result = $mysqli->query($is_field_query)) == false) {        
    die($mysqli->error);        
}   
$is_true = $is_field_result->num_rows;
$is_field_result->close();
return $is_true;

}

function get_content($mysqli, $column, $table, $requested) {

$get_content_query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $column='$requested'";
if (($get_content_result = $mysqli->query($get_content_query)) == false) {
    die($mysqli->error);
}
$get_content_row = $get_content_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$get_content = $get_content_row["content"];
$get_content_result->close();
return $get_content;

}
```

Comment: I found this out on my own. I would be more than happy to give reference or link to anyone who helped me solve this.

Comment: I never saw the answers submitted, I'm embarrased at the simplicity of my problem.